# onClick() crashes program "bignerdranch" "criminalintent" project

Tags: android, onclick, fatal-error, buffer-overflow, executors

i am new to android programming but i have some prior java experience. i am working on a project from the big nerd ranch guide to android programming. because i lack experience with android i am pretty much copying the code while i learn and not trying to get creative with it. however i have reached a point in the criminal intent application where my the app crashes every time i click an item in my RecyclerView. i have searched the web and found other problems kind of like this one but they aren't helping me figure this out. as i have said i am new to android and extras, intents and all that. can anyone help me identify the cause of this and how to fix it? i am posting some of my code as well as the Exceptions stack trace. this is the list fragment that contains the recycler view:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.IllegalFormatCodePointException;
import java.util.List;

public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

    mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
    mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}//end onCreate

private void updateUI(){
    CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
    List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();

    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }else {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}//end updateUI()

private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;
    private Crime mCrime;
    private ImageView mSolvedImageView;

    public CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent){
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this); 

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mSolvedImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    }//end constructor

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        try {
            Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
            startActivity(intent); // something wrong with the activity starting when clicked!
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("ONCLICK", e.toString());
            }
    }//end onCLick()

    public void bind(Crime crime){
        mCrime = crime;
        mTitleTextView.setText(crime.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mSolvedImageView.setVisibility(crime.isSolved() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }//end bind()

}//end CrimeHolder inner Class

private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder>{

    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes){
        mCrimes = crimes;
    }//end constructor
    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        return new CrimeHolder(layoutInflater, parent);

    }// end onCreateViewHolder

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position){
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bind(crime);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mCrimes.size();
    }

}//end CrimeAdapter inner Class

}//end CrimeListFragment class
```

and here is the class for the activity that is supposed to be launched on click:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CrimePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private List<Crime> mCrimes;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId){
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimePagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

    UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.crime_view_pager);
    mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }
    });
}// end onCreate()

}//end crimePagerAtivity class
```

and here is the code for the CrimeLab class:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CrimeLab {
private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
private List<Crime> mCrimes;

public static CrimeLab get(Context context){
    if(sCrimeLab == null){
        sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
    }

    return sCrimeLab;
}//end get()

private CrimeLab(Context context){

}//end constructor

public List<Crime> getCrimes(){
    mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        Crime crime = new Crime();
        crime.setTitle("Crime #" + i);
        crime.setSolved(i % 2 == 0); //every other crime will be checked!
        mCrimes.add(crime);
    }
    return mCrimes;
}//end getCrimes

public Crime getCrime(UUID id){
    for (Crime crime : mCrimes){
        if (crime.getId().equals(id)){
            return crime;
        }
    }
 return null;
}//end getCrime()

}//end CrimeLab class
```

and here is my Exeptions stack trace that is logged from my try/catch block in CrimeHolders onClick():

```
04-30 09:11:33.090 2526-14527/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                           com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                            Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                               at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                               at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

thanks in advance for the help.

here is the application only log. not sure if this helps at all:

```
04-30 09:11:34.042 14542-14542/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
(already on)
04-30 09:11:34.043 14542-14542/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using 
defaults: x86
04-30 09:11:34.187 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent-1/lib/x86
04-30 09:11:34.203 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent 
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-30 09:11:34.298 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent 

04-30 09:11:34.298 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent 
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
04-30 09:11:34.298 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-30 09:11:34.623 14542-14572/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-30 09:11:34.623 14542-14572/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-30 09:11:34.624 14542-14572/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-30 09:11:34.624 14542-14572/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-30 09:11:34.802 14542-14542/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

OK, so here is what i have now for a stack trace:

```
[ 04-30 13:21:32.818  5236: 5236 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host 
Connection established 0x92014100, tid 5236
04-30 13:29:45.065 5236-5236/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 5236

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.Crime.getTitle()' on a null object reference

at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:50)

at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)

at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)

at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)

at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)

at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)

at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)

at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)

at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)

at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)

at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: That stack trace does not appear to be coming from your app. What evidence do you have that this is coming from your process?

Comment: none. i looked into it and you are right. . . that isn't from my application. i have added the application only log.

Comment: doesn't even seem like i get much (if any) of a message when  the program crashes and it always crashes when i click an itemView. i figured this would have to be something in my onClick() method but now i am not so sure. don't know what else could be causing this.

Comment: If you are truly crashing, there will be a Java stack trace in LogCat coming from your app.

Comment: All I get is a pop up on the emulator screen that says "criminalintent has stopped" and then the app closes and restarts. I Probably should have said that earlier.

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` -- that should result in a Java stack trace associated with your app. If you are using Android Studio, change "Show only selected application" to "No filters" and change the severity filter to "Error", and try to find it.

Comment: i did what you said and now i have a new stack trace associated with the application. thanks. i feel that i am at least back on the right track now. let me know if you spot where i am making the mistake.

Comment: You are passing in a `null` `Crime` object to `CrimeFragment`, apparently. Step through your code using the debugger and try to determine why that value is `null`.

Comment: so i have been stepping through my code with the debugger like you said and im finding some stuff i dont quite understand.the Exception is thrown at the line "Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());" and when i step through it i find mId and mCrime are defined ... however, as i step into the code for the newIntent method i find that in Bundle.java in the constructor is apparnently where the exception is thrown.  "Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.os.Bundle.toString()" . is the message that i get.